# How to assert input on a chained mock method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Im using PHPunit 8.3.5 and I'm trying to check wether a method gets the right parameter.

*Example code:*

```
$this->registry->get($thing)->apply(EXAMPLE::SUBMIT);
$this->registry->get($thing)->apply(EXAMPLE::CANCEL);
```

I have two functions, functionA uses the first example line, functionB the second. I need to make sure functionA uses SUBMIT and nothing else, and the same for Bs case.

**The problem:**

- I can use a `->method('apply')->with()` with a callback to test wether it gets the right input
- I can create a `willReturn` for `->method('get')->with()` to return a simple class with `apply` as function
- I can't figure out how to combine the two

```
$registryMock = $this->createMock(Registry::class);
$registryMock->method('get')->willReturn(new class {
    public function apply(){} // <-- I need to assert the input of this method
});
$registryMock->method('apply')->with(self::callback(function($order, $status){
    return $status === EXAMPLE::SUBMIT;
}));
```

---

How can I combine those two methods? I've also tried `get->apply`, but that wasnt it.
*Please note: Rewriting the actual code is not an option.*

Comment: I'm not sure what type of object `$thing` is, but I would create a mock of that object with an assertion on it that the apply function gets called with your desired parameter. Then instead of having a new class in your `willReturn` you can use the mock you just created.

Comment: The `apply` method returns `self`, so whatever type it is, doesnt matter, right?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't matter. But the `get` function does return a certain object. If you can mock that object and put an assertion on it. Then make sure that that mock is the variable that gets returned from `$registryMock->method('get')->willReturn($objectMock);` Then you can assert that apply is called with the right parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment of Dirk:

You create a mock first the 2nd function like you would normally. You then create a mock that returns the previous mock:

```
// first we create a mock for the last in the chain, here '->apply()'
$registryMockApply = $this->createMock(Registry::class);
$registryMockApply->expects(self::once())->method('apply')->with(
    self::equalTo(EXAMPLE::SUBMIT),
);

// Then the one before that, here '->get()', which returns the previous mock
$registryMock = $this->createMock(Registry::class);
$registryMock->method('get')->willReturn($registryMockApply);

// Together resulting in '->get()->apply()'
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I imagined it. Of course if you want to make it work for both calls you would replace `self::once()` with `self::exactly(2)` and then on the return part you can use `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls()`.